# Mouse sensitivity reset after replugging

Tags: xorg, mouse, udev, xinput, input

After complete system upgrade yesterday my mouse sensitivity get reset every time I replug it. This happens often since I have my peripherals attached to my monitor which I use as a dock to switch between 2 computers.

Workarounds I've tried so far:

1. Setupping a rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d` to call a script to set the sensitivity when the mouse is replugged:
   `/etc/udev/rules.d/config-mouse-roccat.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add" \
, ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e7d" \
, ATTRS{idProduct}=="2e23" \
, ENV{DISPLAY}=":0" \
, ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority" \
, RUN+="/home/lehdari/.scripts/config_mouse_roccat.sh"
```

`/home/lehdari/.scripts/config_mouse_roccat.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh
xinput set-prop "ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone XTD Optical Mouse" 157 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

The script itself works fine and gets called when tested with `udevadm test` as instructed at https://linuxconfig.org/tutorial-on-how-to-write-basic-udev-rules-in-linux, but does not work nevertheless.

2. Adding a xorg configuration file as instructed at https://www.reddit.com/r/voidlinux/comments/gwnc3m/mouse_speed_in_xfce_libinput/:

`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone XTD Optical Mouse"
        Driver "libinput"
        MatchIsPointer "yes"
        Option "AccelProfile" "flat"
        Option "AccelSpeed" "-0.7"
        Option "ScrollMethod" "button"  
EndSection
```

Neither of these does work. (I guess the xorg conf couldn't work even on theory since the config gets called only when the X server is initialized)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, try add `MatchProduct "ROCCAT"` and reboot.

Comment: Same problem here, but with a Bluetooth mouse. Every time I reconnect, my mouse acceleration profile is resetted to "default" which means "adaptive", although "flat" is set in `gnome-tweaks`. Happens only with X11 on Ubuntu 20.10. It started to happen several months ago, while I was still using 20.04. Are your mouse settings restored after reloading Gnome with `alt+f2` and then `r`? Mine are.

Comment: This is serious enough to backport to 20.04 I think.

Comment: @DMT would you merge your comments in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was already merged, see: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/1553